# Why can't an unsigned char properly display a hex value

Tags: c++, char, hex

I am trying to create an array of 1 byte values, using unsigned chars to hold the values.

my code looks like this:

```
unsigned char state[4][4] = {   {0xd4, 0xe0, 0xb8, 0x1e},
                                {0xbf, 0xb4, 0x41, 0x27},
                                {0x5d, 0x52, 0x11, 0x98},
                                {0x30, 0xae, 0xf1, 0xe5}};
```

Where each value is 2 hex digits which makes a byte. However, when I attempt to print the array out using

```
    cout << "\nInitial State \n------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << state[x][y] << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

I don't get the hex value, but rather weird symbols

```
Initial State
---------------------
0Ô 0à 0¸ 0 
0¿ 0´ 0A 0' 
0] 0R 0 0˜ 
00 0® 0ñ 0å
```

I understand the 0s come from set(w) and setfill('0') but I don't understand why it isn't showing the proper values. However, if I make the state an unsigned long, I then get the proper values.

So I'm confused. If a char holds exactly one byte, why can't the char display the byte as a hex value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout` is specialized to output the `char` type as a character, not a number. That goes for unsigned chars too. You get around it by casting to an `unsigned int`.

```
cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned int>(state[x][y]) << " ";
```

Comment: And in the dupe answer, there was an extensive discussion about the correct/best casting style already.